# How to freeze package version in requirements?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I have installed the a Python Package with `pip install pyjwt[crypto]` and `pip freeze` shows me different packages that was installed by that action.

What do I need to put in my `requirements.txt` to correctly freeze the versions I am developing with? I dont want to put to much in the `requirements.txt`, only what is needed for rebuilding the environment later.

Output pip:

```
...
pyjwt[crypto] in ..\site-packages (2.8.0)
cryptography>=3.4.0 in ..\site-packages (from pyjwt[crypto]) (41.0.4)
cffi>=1.12 in ..\site-packages (from cryptography>=3.4.0->pyjwt[crypto]) (1.16.0)         
pycparser in ..\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=3.4.0->pyjwt[crypto]) (2.21)
...
```

Output pip freeze:

```
   ...
   cffi==1.16.0        
   cryptography==41.0.4
   pycparser==2.21
   PyJWT==2.8.0
   ...
```

Is it ok to put only `PyJWT[crypto]==2.8.0` into `requirements.txt`?

When I put to much into `requirements.txt` I would make it harder to install additional packages in the future ... I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep your requirements.txt flexible enough, and use a constraint files.

This constraint file is basically the output of pip freeze, and pins all versions, including their dependencies. If you need to add a dependency or upgrade, just do this in requirements.txt and regenerate the constraint file. That way, you are guaranteed to have consistent deployment.

Technically:

```bash
# Create the constraint file
pip freeze > constraint.txt

# use it:
pip install -c constraint.txt
```

Official doc: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#constraints-files

Answer (score 2):

For the "pyjwt[crypto]" package, you can specify the version along with the necessary dependencies like this:

```
PyJWT[crypto]==2.8.0
cryptography==41.0.4
cffi==1.16.0
pycparser==2.21
```

**To install these packages listed in your "requirements.txt"**

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

However, consider how specific you want to be in your "requirements.txt" for other software. It's normally a good idea to give versions for every dependency, but if necessary, you may also define a minimum version or a version range to allow for some flexibility.